# Gem for kind-of-MS Word text formating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm wondering, if there some kind of gem, which formats text input in way simular to Stackoverflow.
I mean, for example, there is form. If you click button, selected line is wraped with special tag symbol, and when you outut text from field, some CSS properties are given, based on these tags (making part of text bold, italic, so on, cod sample like here).
I think, that kind of gem very possibly exists, but can't find with google:don't know exactly what to search, and english is not my native.
Thank your for help.

Comment: You can look into Mercury: http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) and its [gem](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails). Better than TinyMCE and CKEditor in my opinion.

Gem also has support for s3 uploads